# Query mysql database in extjs

Tags: php, mysql, database, html, extjs

We are developing an extjs app that retrieves data from database via php and mysql. We see that it is possible, however we are curious about other possibility of accessing mysql database with extjs.

In fact, we are not sure whether this old-school way is the way to do it efficiently in extjs.

So are there other methods available for extjs?

Comment: Isn't extjs client-side?

Comment: @eggyal It is, a javascript framework.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use ExtJS server side. You'd probably need to utilize Node.js...there are MySQL drivers for Node by the way.

Here is a project that uses ExtJS models on the back end with Node. This might help you get an idea of what is possible.

https://github.com/storminwalker/node-extjs